# Cohomology of classifying spaces of exceptional Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, homology-cohomology

Given an exceptional Lie group $G$ and maximal torus $T$ thereof, the inclusion $T \hookrightarrow G$ induces a map $BT \to BG$ of classifying spaces and a cohomological pullback $$H^*(BG) \cong H^*(BT)^W \hookrightarrow H^*(BT)$$ as the subring of Weyl group invariants. Except for that of $G_2$, these Weyl groups range from "large" to absurdly large, but it seems vaguely possible that these inclusions of polynomial rings might nevertheless be comprehensible. Is that the case?

Or if, more likely, explicit generators for $H^*(BG)$ wouldn't fit in this answer space, where could I find a reference for these inclusions?

NB: I am completely happy taking coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these polynomial algebras are known; this is probably very classical material but I don't know a reference. Their generators have cohomological degree $2d$ where $d$ runs over the numbers from [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism). For example, $H^{\bullet}(BG_2, \mathbb{Q})$ is a polynomial algebra on generators of degrees $4$ and $12$. You might want to look up some material on Coxeter groups; IIRC there's some Coxeter group magic you can use to compute these degrees.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't having any doubts that they were known, and know the list of degrees (each one more than those of generators for the exterior algebra $H^*(G;\mathbb Q)$), but still am not sure where to find them written out.

Comment: @jdc: ah, I see. I wasn't clear on what exactly you knew and what you were asking for. See, for example, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37602/polynomial-invariants-of-the-exceptional-weyl-groups.

Comment: I realize now that I'm not quite sure if I've asked exactly the right question. Polynomial generators of $H^*(BG)$ as a subalgebra of $H^*(BT)$ aren't particularly unique, but I really want to see these generators as images of generators of $H^*(G)$ under transgression. It seems as if for that purpose I need to identify particular polynomial generators. Is that the case, or is the indeterminacy in generators in fact covered by the bottom rows of later pages of the Serre spectral sequence of $G \to EG \to BG$ being quotients of earlier ones?

Comment: @jdc: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll try to be clearer. In the Serre spectral sequence of the fibration $G \to EG \to BG$, the cohomology of the (weakly contractible) total space is trivial, so the generators of the bottom row of the $E_2$ page, essentially $H^*(BG)$, each are eventually mapped to under an edge homomorphism by some element of the leftmost column, $H^*(G)$. What I'm really interested is the images under $H^*(G) \to H^*(BG) \hookrightarrow H^*(BT)$ of these prescribed generators of $H^*(G)$. They will collectively generate the Weyl group invariants, but there is usually some choice ...

Comment: ... in generators for $H^*(BT)^W$. What I was wondering is whether this indeterminacy means that just knowing generators for the Weyl group invariants of $H^*(BT)$ is insufficient information, or whether in fact this indeterminac arises from the fact that the edge homomorphisms $d_r$ are maps from subgroups of $H^r(G)$ to quotients of $H^{r+1}(BG)$. I thought perhaps that the indeterminacy in choice of generators could actually be a manifestation of the fact that for some generator $x \in H^r(G)$, the image $d_r x$ is actually only a class in the $(r+1)^{\mathrm{st}}$ graded ...

Comment: ... component of the quotient ring $H^*(BG)/(\mathrm{im}\  d_j : j < r)$. Is this a fair read on the situation?

Comment: @jdc: I'm still not sure exactly what you're asking, but based on my limited understanding of the Serre spectral sequence, it does seem to me like you only get maps from $H^{\bullet}(G)$ to the associated graded of $H^{\bullet}(BG)$ at best.

Comment: My understanding is that the associated graded comes, in each degree, along the diagonal. That is, associated with a fibration $F \to E \to B$, one has a filtration $(F^p H^k(E))_{0 \leq p \leq k}$ of $H^k(E)$, and $E_\infty^{p,k-p} \cong F^p H^k(E)/F^{p+1} H^k(E)$. My indeterminacy in the map comes from the fact that $d_r\colon E_r^{0,r-1} \to E_r^{r,0}$ is only a map from a subalgebra of $H^*(G)$ to a quotient algebra of $H^*(BG)$, which is in some sense a grading phenomenon, I guess, but I don't think has to do with the associated graded per se. But I could be misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you please give a reference where I can read about $H^*(BG)$... Preferably in your  page https://qchu.wordpress.com/ which helped me many times :) :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik One standard reference on this result might be Hsiang's book on transformation groups. I can provide you a copy if you can't find it, and more specific information if I know what you're looking for. Sorry for not having seen this comment sooner.